# return a new Eloquent collection with modified values from one column

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I have a Slim application that uses a database that stores several items. Each item has its weight stored in grams. I want to allow users to switch between metric and US customary units (pounds and ounces). When I output the items, I'm grouping them by category in a couple different ways and also giving the sum by category. Unless the conversion from grams to ounces is done up front (in the route file) the math won't work since I'm having to round. I don't want any decimals in my ounces.

I'll just put an if statement in that checks if the user is using metric or US. If they are using US I want to modify the values in the grams column to ounces, and then return the entire collection, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

The `transform()` or `map()` methods seem like they would do this, but I'm unable to select the individual column values I want to change. The documentation only shows these methods at work on very simple flat collections. I thought I could use merge(), but that will only work if the array I'm merging in has the same key as the one in the array I'm trying to overwrite.

```
<?php

use Cache\Gear\Gear;

$app->get('/:username/gear', $authenticated(), function() use($app) {

$userId = $app->auth->id;

$collection = collect($app->item->where('user_id', $userId)->get());

$pack = $collection->where('status', 1)->groupBy('category');

// if user is using US customary units
    // Convert grams to ounces and return the collection

// else user is using metric
    // $totalWeight = $collection->where('status', 1)->sum('grams');

$storage = $collection->where('status', 0)->groupBy('category');

$app->render('user/gear.php', [
    'pack' => $pack,
    'storage' => $storage,
    'totalWeight' => $totalWeight
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-transform):

```
$collection->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    $item->grams = $item->grams*0.035274;
    return $item;
});
```

Comment: This works as advertised. I modified it slightly to round the ounces out. As usual the solution was much simpler that I thought it would be. Thanks!